# Configuring Windows Authentication on SQLEXPRESS

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, windows-authentication

I've successfully followed the many tutorials to enable remote connections to my SQLEXPRESS Server. I'm now trying to connect remotely through SQL Server Authentication and the connection works, however I get the following error:

"The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication"

From reading about it is evident that I need to add my Windows account to the server in order to allow me to login. I would normally follow these tutorials through, however all of these require extra SQL tools installed in order to do so. All that is installed on my server is SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Do I need to upgrade the version in order to achieve what I'm after?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the computers in a Windows domain, or just a workgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Ensure that your user account exists on the machine you're trying to connect to (same account and password in a workgroup) - or that you at least have rights to connect (for a domain)

2.) To create users and manage permissions you'll really want SSMSE (SQL Server Management Studio Express) since it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I installed SQL Server Management Studio and it made setup a breeze. Thanks for the suggestion.